# Is it possible make the surface of wood harder?

Tags: cutting-board, epoxy, physical-protection

I'm planning to build a countertop for the kitchen out of glued 1 x 1 pieces of pine. I have glued the pieces together and it looks good, but after working with it for a while, I have realized that it is softer than I initially thought, so I was wondering if there is any treatment for the surface to make it stronger? It feels like if there is a heavy object falling on it, will make a "beautiful" dent in it. I can see videos with people filling gaps with epoxy and that epoxy looks strong, but is epoxy an alternative for this? Can it be applied to the surface only? What other solutions would you recommend for this?

Comment: Make sure you visit the other Q&A on the subject of kitchen countertops, as your answer might be there.

Comment: You are facing multiple issues.  Boards for kitchen countertops are normally selected for their hardness as a priority. Pine is one of the softness wood and a poor choice for any type of work surface. Treating softer woods to make them hard raise these issue. Any  chemical or surface treatment must be food safe,  Breaks in the surface would lead to contamination.

Comment: In the earliest days of what we now refer to as "Danish oil" it was stated by the manufacturer that it hardened or toughened the surface of the wood, IIRC by more than double, which is possible on a small scale but an exaggeration in a broader sense. Anyway in principle "Danish oil" or another penetrating finish can still do this, and dilute varnish AKA wiping varnish (note: make your own, don't buy it) will do the same. You can also get penetrating epoxies now which dry extremely tough, but they can be surprisingly expensive. [contd]

Comment: However, the elephant in the room is that this is soft softwood, and there's just no getting around how soft the material is underneath a tough skin that you might be able to create.

Comment: @Programmer66, *"Pine is one of the softness wood and a poor choice for any type of work surface."* not if you don't mind that it marks. Remember there are many woodworking benches with pine worktops! Plus I've seen kitchen tables built in the 19th century from softwoods that have withstood nearly 200 years of continual use. *"Any chemical or surface treatment must be food safe"* They all are. The issue of food safety with finishes is a red herring.

Comment: @Graphus note that old growth softwoods are actually quite hard, especially when compared to modern whitewood/SPF you can get in the big box store. Even southern yellow pine you can find in the larger dimensional lumber (typically 2x8 and above) is significantly harder than plain 2x4s (and that's still softer than 100 year old trees of the same type!).

Comment: @EliIser I agree! My house is about 120 years old. I often joke that it was made of petrified wood because it's so difficult to drill through the old studs! (I don't know if they used pine, but I wouldn't be surprised if they used whatever hardwood was available from locally felled trees to build this place.)

Comment: @FreeMan if you are in North America, most dimension lumber was made of fir. But it was old-growth fir and tough as nails. Splintered easily and gave you slivers all day long, but tough. It was also rough cut/planed to nominal and then dried, so it is probably larger in width and thickness than modern dimension lumber, so you have to go through  more material. But white oak was also plentiful. I like to say my house is made with load bearing trim -- the "finish" nails going into the "trim" are massive.

Comment: More to the point, many commercial chopping _blocks_ are made with softwood, but those are allowed to get really torn up before getting resurfaced regularly. There is always a trade-off between saving the edge of a knife and the surface of a block, and the knife wins when (say) cutting up chicken pieces all day. But for _boards_ even commercial kitchens use much harder woods, and usually they are unfinished.

Comment: Wow, thank you guys for your comments and discussions. I was afraid that I made a mistake doing this, but I guess I will just carry on and not freak out about it. I really love the texture especially because of the knots. It’s beautiful like this, with this pattern, and I wouldn’t have chosen oak because it is expensive and the one that I found is too smooth and boring. The other option was poplar, which I also didn’t like.

Comment: @CuriousPaul based on the original post and the comments it looks like you are going to have a pine countertop with no finish at all. Is that correct? Here's a nice article from This Old House https://www.thisoldhouse.com/kitchens/21018085/all-about-wood-countertops

Comment: I was planning to put a Butcher Block Oil and Finish. I did that for a dining table and it looks very nice, but I am just a bit afraid that I will make dents in it over time. For instance, I signed a paper directly on the dining table by pushing the pen on the paper. Guess what happened? That was a stupid rookie mistake. The article is good for the inspiration. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: @CuriousPaul, yeah the price difference between oak and other woods can be significant! And while oak IS a classic for worktops it does have a major drawback in that it can stain badly from any iron salts in water. As for poplar, probably fine but boring as hell! And pine can be fine for heavily used surfaces. As I've referred to many times I have a pine chopping board that is well over 30 years old and still going strong, and it was not babied in any way. I regularly scrub it with a pot scourer to clean and it was used many times as a trivet for hot pans and casseroles straight from the oven.

Comment: Thank you everyone for sharing and for all the advice. A lot of great unexpected information. I appeciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments have a lot of good discussion about wood choice, but to directly answer your question, yes.  You can use epoxy to make a surface harder.  However, you need to be careful about your choice of epoxy.

Normal hardware store epoxy is designed for repair work, i.e. bonding two parts together.  To do this effectively it needs to be quite thick.  This will prevent it from "soaking into" the surface you're treating.  Instead, you should use a "penetrating epoxy sealer".  This type of epoxy is much thinner and will "penetrate" deeper into the wood you're treating.

Epoxy (along with most wood glues and finishes) is generally food safe once it has fully cured.

I would recommend doing a test on a scrap to see how the epoxy will effect your finishing.

Comment: Just know that, as it wears, it will slough off epoxy into your food. Not _necessarily_ harmful, but plastics are not something I want _more_ of in my diet.